# Parser for CNF formulas

Tags: java, parsing

I have a parser for CNF formulas in [Dimacs format](http://logic.pdmi.ras.ru/~basolver/dimacs.html), which is very slow. Any suggestion on how to improve its speed? I did some profiling and I might have to replace `Scanner`. Is there anything faster?

A possible input for the parser is:

> ```
> c A sample .cnf file.
> p cnf 3 2
> 1 -3 0
> 2 3 -1 0
> ```

The code:

```
/**
 * Parses a stream for a CNF instance.                                                                  
 *
 * @param source input stream                                                                           
 * @return read skeleton
 * @throws ParseException if stream contains an invalid instance                                        
 */
private static Skeleton parseStream(final InputStream source)                                           
    throws IOException, ParseException {                                                                
  Scanner scanner = new Scanner(source);                                                                

  // Skip comments
  try {                                                                                                 
    String token = scanner.next();                                                                      
    while (token.equals("c")) {                                                                         
      scanner.nextLine();
      token = scanner.next();                                                                           
    }
    if (!token.equals("p")) {
      throw new ParseException(                                                                         
          "Excepted 'p', but '" + token + "' was found");                                               
    }
  } catch (NoSuchElementException e) {
    throw new ParseException("Header not found");                                                       
  }

  // Reads header
  int numVariables, numClauses;                                                                         
  try {
    String cnf = scanner.next();                                                                        
    if (!cnf.equals("cnf")) {                                                                           
      throw new ParseException(                                                                         
          "Expected 'cnf', but '" + cnf + "' was found");                                               
    }
    numVariables = scanner.nextInt();                                                                   
    numClauses = scanner.nextInt();
  } catch (NoSuchElementException e) {
    throw new ParseException("Incomplete header");                                                      
  }
  logger.debug("p cnf " + numVariables + " " + numClauses);                                             

  // Reads clauses
  Skeleton skeleton = new Skeleton(numVariables);
  try {
    while (numClauses > 0) {
      int literal = scanner.nextInt();
      skeleton.cnf.add(literal);
      if (literal == 0) {
        numClauses--;
      }
    }
  } catch (NoSuchElementException e) {
    throw new ParseException(
        "Incomplete problem: " + numClauses + " clauses are missing");
  }

  return skeleton;                                                                                      
}
```

Comment: I suggest you to use [ANTLR](http://www.antlr.org/) to generate parsers. It also provides you with some useful operations. You can find all you need. When you don't want to just learn how to write a parser from scratch then you should not reinvent the wheel.

Comment: Are you sure it's the parsing that is the bottleneck here? Simply reading data from disk is an expensive operation, so, it could be just that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use a [`BufferedInputStream`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/BufferedInputStream.html) to speed up the disk access. If that's not enough, you can read the file line-by-line and use [`split()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29) to break it into individual numbers.

Comment: Same exact suggestion I was going to give